# How does the performance of Kakadu change with compression ratio?

Tags: jpeg2000

Is there any analysis of how the compression and decompression performance of Kakadu changes with compression ratio? E.g., if we change the compression ratio from 2 to 10, how much slower will Kakadu (de)compress the same image?

(Kakadu is a library for working with JPEG2000.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the performance doesn't depend of the compression ratio.

The only exception is lossless compression, which is faster because it skips the step of cutting off the "lost" info.